# session management in standalone applications

Tags: java, session

I have a standalone application which can be installed on multiple machines.
Need to do session management for each user.
Currently we are maintaining a database table to save userid,login and logout time and login status.(which is"Y" when user is logged in and "N: when user has logged out.) This allows a user to login to only one instance of the application.

Now the issue is: If system crashes on one Machine, the status remains "Y" for that user in the DB,
and doesnt allow the user to login again.How to Identify a system crash?
Alternatively, how to store login information wrt Mac Id's?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always override the last login.

For example there is terminal A and terminal B
When user logs in on terminal A he has an instance there.
When he switches to terminal B login goes as normal, but anyone else working on terminal A will be forcibly logged out.

Thats the way the remote desktop of windows works, and it prevents a lot of the issues you encounter with other mechanics.

Comment: Let me explain my scenario: User1 logs in to Terminal A, system makes an entry in the table with Status "Y", User1 logs out Status changed to "N", User1 logs in again, system checks if the Status is "N" , only then it allows user to Login(whether it's on Terminal A or B). this works fine as long as we dont have a  crash....that is, USer1 logs in on Terminal A, application crashes and status remains "Y", because of which the next time user logs in, either through Terminal A or B, system checks status in DB table, its "Y" therefore doesnt allow user1 to login,

Comment: Problem is identifying a crash, or finding a better way to maintain User's login Status considering Any user is allowed to login using any terminal, as long as he is running only one instance of the application over the network

Comment: You are approaching the issue wrong. **always override the last session** Have a method that checks the login status every 10 seconds if the session is valid. If its not valid it auto closes the client. That way when the user logs on on another terminal the other open and active client gets closed. That way you dont have to worry about crashes. Last login is the valid login, no matter from where the login was.

Comment: ok,so your approach( in DB terms) is that when a user logs in to Terminal A, I set the status to "Y" and I need to have a method that checks if its a valid login every 10seconds,what exactly do you mean by a Valid login? (In terms of the credentials or the Status?) Also,when the the same user logs in from another terminal B, then I should check if status is "Y" already(as in another user is logged in) and then how will I know on Terminal A that the user has also logged in from Terminal B and the "the other open and active client gets closed"? Thanks

Comment: Upon login a user gets appoint a current key Y2014. Every time the user logs in he gets a different key. Your server polls the client if the current key is still there. server -> client "gimme your key" client to server <- "user=X, key=Y2014" server to client -> Okay, good to go. When user logs in on other terminal he gets the key Y2015 making the key on the other terminal invalid so the server sends to the first teminal on poll "You ded  man" and the terminal self closes.